# SQL: Select Top 2 Query is Excluding Records with more than 2 Records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I just joined after having a problem writing a query in MS Access. I am trying to write a query that will pull out the first two valid samples in from a list of replicated sample results and then would like to average the sample values. I have written a query that does pull samples with *only* two valid samples and averages these values. However, my query doesn't pull samples where there are more than two valid sample results. Here's my query:

```
SELECT temp_platevalid_table.samp_name AS samp_name, avg (temp_platevalid_table.mean_conc) AS fin_avg, count(temp_platevalid_table.samp_valid) AS sample_count
FROM Temp_PlateValid_table
WHERE (Temp_PlateValid_table.id In (SELECT TOP 2 S.id
                                    FROM Temp_PlateValid_table as S
                                    WHERE S.samp_name = S.samp_name and s.samp_valid=1 and S.samp_valid=1
                                    ORDER BY ID))
GROUP BY Temp_PlateValid_table.samp_name
HAVING ((Count(Temp_PlateValid_table.samp_valid))=2)
ORDER BY Temp_PlateValid_table.samp_name;
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
ID      Samp_Name     Samp_Valid     Mean_Conc
1       54d2d2        1              15
2       54d2d2        1              20
3       54d2d2        1              25
```

The average mean_conc should be 17.5, however, with my current query, I wouldn't receive a value at all for 54d2d2. Is there a way to tweak my query so that I get a value for samples that have more than two valid values? Please note that I'm using MS Access, so I don't think I can use fancier SQL code (partition by, etc.).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think the problem is that you are comparing the samp_name to the samp_name from the same table when you are wanting to compare them one from the inner query and one from the outer query. The example from  Gordon below shows what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select pv.samp_name, avg(pv.value_conc)
from Temp_PlateValid_table pv
where pv.samp_valid = 1 and
      pv.id in (select top 2 id
                from Temp_PlateValid_table as pv2
                where pv2.samp_name = pv.samp_name and pv2.samp_valid = 1
               )
group by pv.samp_name;
```

You might need `avg(pv.value_conc * 1.0)`.

Comment: This query will give an average of 17 for the example in the OP's question. At least it does when I'm using SSMS. I haven't checked with MS Access.